# How to upgrade self-hosted (centOS) kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, centos, kubernetes, upgrade

I would like to upgrade kubernetes from 1.5 to a recent version (i installed it with yum install kubernetes-master kubernetes-client ...) but i don't understand how to achieve it.

Is there yum repos to upgrade kubernetes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What repository are you using?

Comment: I am using this one :

[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no official (with official I mean supported by the kubernetes team) way of installing kubernetes on any linux distro using system packages.

Centos provides packages for the old 1.5 version on their extra repository, the packages you actually have installed.

I think you best choice is to install another cluster using an officially supported way, such as **[kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops)** (if you are on AWS) or **[kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/)** and migrate your services in the new cluster. This way you have a guarantee that you'll be able to upgrade to future releases.

Please note that kubeadm is not production ready

If you want to proceed this way, you can find a list of installation methods at this page: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/pick-right-solution/

Comment: I am using my own servers to hosting kubernetes cluster so kops is not a possible way.
About kubeadm, as you said, it is not production ready. So how can i have a production ready kubernetes cluster hosted by my own ?

Comment: I was asking the same question and found [Rancher](http://rancher.com/kubernetes/). Not sure if that's what you need, though.  It's free.

Comment: I am using kubeadm on my preproduction cluster and it works just fine for my needs

Comment: Ok thanks, maybe I will use kubeadm. However, i don't understand why there is no way to update my cluster without rebuild a full cluster.

Comment: Because nobody is maintaining the packages you used to install it. That sucks but I guess we can't do much about it

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! So, my last question is : what i have to use to install my own production-ready kubernetes cluster ?

Comment: Honestly I have no answers about that.